vCenter HA against site failure
How can I prevent vCenter 7 HA across datacenter failure? What is the best method against vCenter site-failure? We have 3 Datacenters and a Enterprise plus license.
Is setting up separate vCenter for each datacenter (with or without HA) the only solution? Is this the recommended method and do I need extra license for each vCenter?
In vCenter 6.5 it seems we can setup vCenter using loadbalancers and external PSC's according to this article. But I'm not sure how to achieve this in vCenter 7 as there is no external PSC in vCenter 7.
